# Square and Quarter Circle

Tags: geometry, circles, problem-solving, area, arc-length

$ABCD$ is a square of side $18$ cm. $F$ is a point inside the square, such that $BCF$ forms an equilateral triangle. $CFA$ is a quarter circle with centre $B$. $E$ is the point on $AB$ such that the area of the region $EFC$ is half that of the area of the quarter circle.

> Find the length of $AE$ (in cm).

[image]

Comment: Hello! It would be useful to show your attempts and give problem context. Also please read the [Question Tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question), [MathJax Guide](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), and take a [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour)! Good Luck. Also, the radius of the circle is 18cm as the side lengths bounding the circle are also the radius.

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your suggestions. Actually, my attempts are really vague, with no more than 3-4 steps. So I am trying to get the solution here if possible. Thanks though. :)

Answer (score 2):

Express the area of $Area(FEBC)$ in two different ways, namely,  $Area\left(FEC\right)+ Area\left(EBC\right)$ and $Area\left(FEB\right)+Area\left(FBC\right)$. Now equate them to get the value of $EB$ and thereafter $AE$.